# How to make longer arrows in math-mode?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, arrows, tikz-arrows

My question is relative to the following problem; in `math-mode`, I want to write an inclusion

```
$C_p^\mathcal{U}\hookrightarrow C_p(X)$
```

However, this is insuficient, since I have written a long document in which every arrow (in `math-mode`) has been either `\longrightarrow` or `\longmapsto`, making this presentation pretty awkward. However, I would like to know if there is a way to implement this long hooked arrow in `math-mode`, or what should be done to be able to use this symbol between text.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\xhookrightarrow` from `mathtools`, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$C_p^\mathcal{U}\hookrightarrow C_p(X)$

$C_p^\mathcal{U}\xhookrightarrow{\quad} C_p(X)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here, `\quad` is just an example. This is an extensible arrow, which will adjust its size to what it written above (or underneath) it, even if this is just some space like `\quad`.

Answer (score 3):

I can add an answer with the use of the [`old-arrows`](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/fonts/old-arrows/doc/old-arrows.pdf) package with the option `[new]`. The old-arrows package provides additional commands for new types of arrows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[new]{old-arrows}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
(\texttt{long hookrightarrow})
$
C_{p}^{\mathcal{U}} \varlonghookrightarrow C_{p}(X)
$

(\texttt{short hookrightarrow})
$C_{p}^{\mathcal{U}} \varhookrightarrow C_p(X)$
\end{document}
```